# got unknown stack while capturing go binary exit point with bpftrace

Tags: linux, go, linux-kernel, ebpf

I want to practice bpftrace tracing go program exit point, such as, `runtime.gopanic` and `os.Exit`, but I'm confused with the result:

```sh
[root@localhost trace-go-func]# bpftrace -c "./binary -mode exit -code 2" trace.bt
Attaching 2 probes...
mode=exit, ecode=2
syscall.Exit(2) called with stack: 
        458080 0x458080 ([unknown])
        487f9e 0x487f9e ([unknown])
        487ee6 0x487ee6 ([unknown])
        433192 0x433192 ([unknown])
        45ba81 0x45ba81 ([unknown])

[root@localhost trace-go-func]# bpftrace -c "./binary -mode panic" trace.bt
Attaching 2 probes...
mode=panic, ecode=0
panic called with stack 
        430280 runtime.gopanic+0 (/root/projects/trace-go-func/binary)
        487f05 main.main+293 (/root/projects/trace-go-func/binary)
        433192 runtime.main+530 (/root/projects/trace-go-func/binary)
        45ba81 runtime.goexit.abi0+1 (/root/projects/trace-go-func/binary)
panic: doPanic

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.doPanic()
        /root/projects/trace-go-func/main.go:31 +0x27
main.main()
        /root/projects/trace-go-func/main.go:22 +0x125
```

`panic` works well, but `os.Exit` could not get stack correctly. I have found symbols with addresses in nm like this, `for x in 458080 487f9e 487ee6; do nm ./binary | grep $x; done`, but only got: [image]

I'm confused now, why `bpftrace` could get the address and symbols while `runtime.gopanic` but `os.Exit`, and even could not matched in `nm`?

Here's my go source code `main.go` and `trace.bt`

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var (
    mode = flag.String("mode", "exit", "choose mode to run and test")
    code = flag.Int("code", 0, "os.Exit code")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Printf("mode=%s, ecode=%d\n", *mode, *code)

    // defer fmt.Println("main quit")

    switch *mode {
    case "panic":
        doPanic()
    case "exit":
        doOSExit(*code)
    }
}

//go:noinline
func doPanic() {
    // fmt.Println("panic calling")
    panic("doPanic")
}

//go:noinline
func doOSExit(code int) (x int) {
    // fmt.Println("os.Exit calling")
    os.Exit(code)
    for ; x < code; x++ {
    }
    return x
}
```

```
uprobe:./binary:runtime.gopanic
{
    printf("panic called with stack %s", ustack(perf));
}

uprobe:./binary:syscall.Exit
{
    printf("syscall.Exit(%d) called with stack: %s", sarg0, ustack(perf));
}
```

| Core | Version |
| --- | --- |
| OS | centos7 |
| Kernel | 5.4.188-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 |
| bpftrace | v0.13.0 |
| go | 1.18 |

Comment: I think such question would have much greated chances of being answered if you were to post on on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts): to my (limited) knowledge none of the Go devs follows the `go` tag here on SO. Also see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community). Oh, and if you will decide to post a message to the list, please post the link to it here, thanks!

Comment: @kostix thanks for your advice, I would check out the mailing list

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/jmiJwzte4rI